# How to generate a new Ethereum address and private key from a command line?

Tags: web3js, private-key

How one can securely generate a new raw private key from a UNIX command line?

This private key can be then imported to wallet apps or web3.js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have openssl installed, you can run

```
openssl rand -hex 32
```

**Note**: This will generate a 32 bytes sequence. It never verifies that the sequence is a valid private key.

There's a tiny possibility that some outputs will not generate a valid private key (a sequence of 32 zeros bytes), or a number above the elliptic curve order (FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141).

If you are really paranoid, you should verify it is a valid private key.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the shortest method, in the sense it is least typing and easy to remember. The only downside is that OpenSSL libraries and tools are somewhat painto to get installed on macOS sometime.

Comment: In the case, what happens if you create a number that is not a valid on the elliptic curve? Would I get a compromisable address or would tools complain when I import it as an account?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa  Good wallet should reject invalid input, poorly programmed will carry on but the output will be undeterministic and might be incompatible other. In the worst case they will assume that it is valid and generate an address that cannot be used. The private key will not generate a valid signature, so you cannot spend funds from the address. Best case wallets will complain and refuse to use the private key.

Comment: Holly F. this actually worked! I also sent $0.01 to that address. I thought ETH addresses are generated when interacting with the network on-chain not on the fly off-chain.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you're using NodeJS (as implied from your question), then you may as well do:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const privateKey = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
```

Comment: Yep! This is good. I was also hoping to find something ultra portable, so that the generation method can be done on any standard POSIX environment

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Any NodeJS solution is ultra portable by definition (since NodeJS is OS agnostic).

Comment: yes, but you still need to install Node.js. It does not come with the default macOS installation. And installing Node just to create a private key is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/dev/urandom` as a safe cryptographic random number generator. The following reads 32 bytes (256 bits) from the random number generator and formats it as a single hex string.

```sh
head -c 32 /dev/urandom|xxd -ps -c 32
```

Example output:

```
bf44080bd48031e2d793f2d8b7bc06f8e52be06fe9fd0d0fd1a8411d04686c3a
```

[More technical information about Ethereum accounts](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-generate-ethereum-addresses-technical-address-generation-explanation-25r3zqo).

Answer (score 3):

Generating with Python and `web3.py`:

```shell
# Web3.py 6.0+
python -c "from web3 import Web3; w3 = Web3(); acc = w3.eth.account.create(); print(f'private key={w3.to_hex(acc._private_key)}, account={acc.address}')"
```

```shell
# Web3.py 5.0 and older
python -c "from web3 import Web3; w3 = Web3(); acc = w3.eth.account.create(); print(f'private key={w3.toHex(acc.privateKey)}, account={acc.address}')"
```

Outputs:

```
private key=0xb62774c4d8dbcbe3641e7d78c80fe04899914d531d010f455788b94885f56446,
 account=0xCFe4DA2084Db71E83b7833Fb267A6caE459e31dD
```