# What is the safest way to generate an ethereum wallet for cold storage?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-key, keystore, cold-storage

I am currently making a DIY cold storage using a desktop computer. I cannot find any good desktop wallet for ethereum cold storage. Something like electrum for BTC.

So, I can only found these 3 ways to generate a new ethereum wallet address.

1. Using `geth` account

This will create a keystore .json file. I need to keep safe the `account password` and `keystore json` file

```
geth account new
```

2. using `web3js`

This will give an output of `address` and `privateKey`. What I need to keep safe is the `privateKey`.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();
const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.create();
console.log(wallet);
```

3. Using `ethereumjs-wallet`

This will give an output of `address` and `privateKey`. What I need to keep safe is the `privateKey`.

```js
const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet')
const ethWallet = Wallet.default.generate();
console.log(`address: ${ethWallet.getAddressString()}`);
console.log(`privateKey: ${ethWallet.getPrivateKeyString()}`);
```

Are these methods safe to generate a new address for cold storage?
Please let me know if you have any other method.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using [MyEtherWallet offline](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/offline/using-mew-offline/). Skip the "Export JSON File" part and head straight to "Downloading and Running MEW Offline". Genereate a new mmemnonic seed on an offline computer and store the seed words in safe places (preferably not on a computer connected to the internet, to keep your secret air-gapped).

Answer (score 0):

You can create Ethereum private key using many UNIX command line tools.

- [Create a random private key using command line tools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-address-and-private-key-from-a-command-line).
- [Create private key from any string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131524/creating-ethereum-private-key-from-a-string/131528#131528)