# Creating Ethereum private key from a string

Tags: private-key

I have a simple string, for example `test` - and I need to convert it to Ethereum private key `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`

What is an algorithm? Which functions should I apply? I want to make it with nodejs.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use the `test` string as a mnemonic and extract private key from it?

Comment: @OneThunder exactly. I wonder how such brain wallets are generated. I know it is not secure to use such private keys, but I am interested for educational purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this using Web3 libraries for programming language:

```js
web3.sha3("my super secret passphrase with a lot of entropy")
```

You can do it like this on a UNIX/Linux command prompt:

```shell
# Needs to have openssl command lines tools installed
printf "supser secret passphra5e" | openssl dgst -sha256
```

```
3c37fb6a9605750240461a90d43ca6742b468479a5ec8380113f6be0bb29168b
```

The only requirement of a private key is that it is 256 bit integer number, or 32 bytes or random data (with [some small limitations](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82946/620))

Note that most simple passphares that are guessable are guessed. For example, any sentence from the bible or other famous book is no go.

Check [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/) for JavaScript and [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/) for Python.

Comment: note sha256 and sha3 are different algorithms which will produce different numbers based on the same string

Comment: Also it's recommended to use key stretching algorithms like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to counter bruteforce attacks on the key! Using fast Hashing algorithms (like SHA) with poor preimages is not a good idea for key derivation!

Answer (score 1):

It’s the simple sha256 encoding.