# How to create an Ethereum wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, web3.py, accounts, python

'Hi everyone!

I'm wondering if anyone has trouble using [web3's create wallet method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet)? I do not have access to `web3.eth.accounts.wallet` command through my Geth's console.

Appreciate any help,
R.

- Geth version: 1.10.12-stable
- Geth's web3 api version: 0.20.1
- OS: Windows
- web3.py version: 5.25.0
- python version: 3.10.1
- I started my geth using the following command: `geth console --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 20000 --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock`
- Related questions: [#2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118693/what-is-web3s-wallet-definition-and-usage) and [#3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum)

Comment: Too many questions in one post. Moreover, how did you start your geth ?

Comment: @Itération122442 , thanks for the reply. I started my geth using the following command:

geth console --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 20000 --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock

Comment: Welcome on this stack, by the way. You should include your comment in the question. Moreover, one post should focus on one question. I recommend you edit this post so that it includes only question 1 and post question 2 and 3 in another post.

Comment: @Itération122442, thanks for the advice. Took it and split up the question to [#2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118693/what-is-web3s-wallet-definition-and-usage) and [#3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum).

Comment: @RoliJ Geth's console uses web3 v0.20, see [this](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/DOCUMENTATION.md) for the old api. In any case web v0.20 doesn't support creating an account, for that you have to use the ["personal API"](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-personal).

Comment: Thank you @Ismael for the reply. I create accounts by using `web3.personal.newAccount("pass_phrase")`. I am wondering what are `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`-base commands do? Are these attempting to create and interact with wallets, like in Bitcoin (which is weird, because of the difference between the concepts in these two networks, as @mikko-ohtamaa pointed out bellow, correctly)? Or it is just creating wallets and accounts inside them and has nothing to do about the wallet concept like the one in Bitcoin?

Comment: @RoliJ It is in the documentation *Contains an in memory wallet with multiple accounts*. It is as Mikko says it manages an array of independent accounts completely unrelated to bitcoin wallets.

Comment: @Ismael, thank you for the comment. You are right. mikko-ohtamaa's clarification on the UTXO/ACCOUNT models used by these two chains, helped me out to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `geth` to create a wallet. Ethereum account is [just a private key that is a large 256-bit random integer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-address-and-private-key-from-a-command-line). Then this private key can be imported to any wallet software or your own program.

- Each Ethereum account has a public key that is derived from a private key that is 256 bit integer
- Ethereum address is the first 160 bits of 256 bit public key
- Most wallets are collection of accounts that are derived from [BIP 39 seed phrase a.k.a mnemonic](https://wolovim.medium.com/ethereum-201-mnemonics-bb01a9108c38)
- For more information see [Cryptograpghy chapter in Mastering Ethereum book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-ethereum/9781491971932/ch04.html)

[Here is an example how to create a private key and public key by hand from command line](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131524/creating-ethereum-private-key-from-a-string/131528#131528).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here, by using "wallet", I am referring to the one in the bitcoin atmosphere, where there is a wallet that owns other accounts (and not accounts in the Ethereum atmosphere). And this is why I unsuccessfully attempted exploring the concept throughout the `web3.eth.accounts.wallet` command. Any revision?

Comment: By the way, I wanted to vote up your answer (however this is not the answer I am looking for, but it is useful for those who might be redirected to this question, one day), but do not have the minimum reputation required for voting. Sorry and thanks again.

Comment: Unlearn what you have learnt it Bitcoin. Your mind is corrupted.

Comment: I'm not saying that "wallet" doesn't have a different meaning in ethereum network. I just want to explore [this method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet) and see what is it trying to do and what is the difference between wallet and account here? What is the definition of wallet in the `web3.personal.listWallets` geth's console command? And what is the difference between this command and `web3.personal.listAccounts` or `web3.eth.accounts`? These are the questions I'm going to explore and the reason I asked this question.

Comment: The [UTXO model](https://arunrajeevan.medium.com/utxo-model-in-bitcoin-vs-account-balance-model-ethereum-c5b47865e9e1) you mentioned in [Q#3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum) helped me understand what you are saying. Wallets has nothing to do with the structure being used in blockchains to track down the balance or handle transactions. It is just a file containing accounts' info and `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`-based commands are just to handle that. Thanks again.