# What is web3's wallet definition and usage?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, web3.py, accounts, python

'Hi everyone!

Is [web3's wallet](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet) definition and usage, the same as in Bitcoin's?

Appreciate any clarification,
R.

- Geth version: 1.10.12-stable
- Geth's web3 api version: 0.20.1
- OS: Windows
- web3.py version: 5.25.0
- python version: 3.10.1
- I started my geth using the following command: `geth console --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 20000 --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock`
- Related questions: [#1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/how-to-create-a-wallet) and [#3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for those who might want to be clarified on the wallet/account concepts on Ethereum, thanks to [@mikko-ohtamaa](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/620/mikko-ohtamaa).

The answer is YES and NO.

Wallets have nothing to do with the structure being used in blockchains to track down the balances or handle transactions. It is just a file containing accounts' info(public/private keys) and `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`-based commands mentioned [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=wallet#wallet) are just to handle that. Thus, from this point of view, the wallet concept is equal in these two atmospheres.

Furthermore, Ethereum does not use the [UTXO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspent_transaction_output), like the one in Bitcoin. [This](https://arunrajeevan.medium.com/utxo-model-in-bitcoin-vs-account-balance-model-ethereum-c5b47865e9e1) is a start point article about that. It uses an account-based model. Thus, from this point of view, the wallet concept is NOT equal in these two atmospheres.

So, having a Bitcoin-like structure to handle transaction flow for centralized exchange structures is impossible to me. Instead, some may use the smart contracts to manage that. You can explore [this approach](https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-simple-erc20-exchange-wallet-c6720e6c8005) for a beginning step towards that. If you are going go further, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118795/how-the-centralized-exchanges-handle-deposits).

I am looking forward any innovative ideas/comments on the subject.