# How to create a wallet for ETH?

Tags: wallets, accounts, keystore

I'm a bit confused on the process now of creating wallets in the Ethereum ecosystem.
At this time I'm creating an application that allows users to create their own wallets but I'm very confused on the process of creating them, coming from `Cardano` the process seems very different.

I've been reading the docs & it seems no one talks about creating `Mnemonic Keys` anymore, but instead use a 'Public & Private' key.

When I create my keys on the client, don't I have to submit them to the network to form an account, the docs explain nothing about this process.

I came across [Clef](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/tools/clef/introduction) but I'm not sure what the recommended steps are to take. Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: I'm using `Geth` alongside `Lighthouse` & it seems `Lighthouse` has all the commands I need to create a wallet & submit them to the network

Comment: Please see here [how to create a wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/118705/620).

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can create a new private key:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const privateKey = ethers.utils.randomBytes(32);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
```

You can store the `privateKey`on a database and query it in order to sign transactions.

Comment: So you don't actually need to submit the created wallet to the network, once you derive public & private keys from a mnemonic sentence?

Comment: Exactly. You store the privateKey in a db and use it to sign transactions. The access to the privateKey can be achieved through auth.