# What is the number of last ethereum private key?

Tags: go-ethereum, python

if ethereum private key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 is number 1 in all ethereum private key sequence, what is the number of last private key FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141?

Comment: [You can confirm the max value of private key here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-address-and-private-key-from-a-command-line/82946#82946).

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum uses de [secp256k1](https://wiki.bitcoinsv.io/index.php/Secp256k1) elliptic curve.

Defining an elliptic curve requires several parameters one of them is `G`, a point in the elliptic curve, `n` the *order* of *G* the elliptic curve. They are define such that `n` is the smallest integer such that `n.G = O`.